# SharePoint Online User Profiles showing incorrect manager

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

We have a few managers that have left the company.  Since those managers left, SharePoint Online user profiles now point to a similarly named person but not the same person.

For instance:

If a person had the following manager that left the company:
FLast@company.com
that person's manager now registers to
FMLast@company.com
who is an entirely different person

Has anyone seen this 'nearest neighbor' behavior before?

Comment: Are you doing AADConnect Synchronization or just cloud only? If you are using AADConnect have you checked the sync logs for the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated the manager values to the correct values in AD and that fixed the issue.  I have no explanation to why the User Profile would apply a similarly named individual as the manager.